# Unwillingly using two different versions of System.Data.Common in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, hololens

I'm currently developing an app for a Microsoft Hololens. 
To use the database libaries of the company I already ported the old .NET Framework libaries into .NET Core 2.0.

I used the Portability Check Tool issued by Microsoft to be sure that I was on the right track.

Apparently my idea worked that's why I included a new UWP App to run on my Hololens.

When I tried using my libary connection commands I encountered the following issue:

> Assembly 'xy' with identity
>   'xy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'System.Data.Common' with identity
>   'System.Data.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

It seems that my newly ported libaries use a higher version of `System.Data.Common` than my Universal Windows project.

I am currently at a loss on how to have an equal version in both projects. 
I already tried a bunch of packages from Nuget and also downgrading my libraries didn't help.

Comment: Adding the Nuget Package with an higher version of System.Data.Common  (at least 4.2.0) on your UWP project does not solve the issue?

Comment: No, I also thought that it might help but it did nothing... I am really lost

Comment: Is your project using an explicit `packages.config`? You may want to convert to the [PackageReference approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), which has more latitude in resolving these conflicts (especially for dependencies of dependencies). And despite all automation, you may still need manual assembly binding redirects.

Comment: What is your uwp app target version and min version? Could you please tell the solution structure?  Did you use [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common/)?  What is the VS template you are creating for the library?

Comment: I am already using the Package Reference approach. @Sunteen Wu  The Min Version is the Anniversary Update so 10.0.14393 the Target Version is Fall Creators Update 10.0.16299. I have 5 projects within my solution and 4 of those are my libraries. Those have the foundation of a .Net Core class library.

Comment: So have you successfully referenced the .Net core class library to UWP app? UWP apps can only reference the .NET standard class library template, not .NET Core class library template.